# How to construct such a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

It's an exercise in the Wedhorn's book:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Give a $k$-scheme $X$ such that:

1. There is a morphism $f:\mathbb A_k^1\rightarrow X$ which is homeomorphic on the topological space.
2. $\dim T_xX=1$ at all except one $x\in X$.
3. $X$ is not reduced.

I have tried $k[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^3,Z^2)$. In this case, we can calculate its jacobbian, and see that the tangent space has dimension $3$ at $0$ but $2$ elsewhere. But in the case $k[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3)$ it satisfies all but condition 3.

My idea is: Since we need to get a "special" point, we may construct a curve which is singular at only one point. (In above cases $X^2-Y^3$ is the curve I need). But I don't know how to modify it to make it satisfy all conditions. Could you help me achieve it? Or could you give an example directly? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you been able to come up with examples which satisfy some of the conditions, but maybe not all of them? Do you have an example which you think works but need help checking it?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for reminder! I have added what I have tried in the question.

Comment: @Richard can you not just take $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/((y^2 - x^3)^2)$ which is clearly not reduced...

Comment: a minor problem with the above will be the stipulation that $\operatorname{char}(k)\neq 2,3 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will work.

Consider $k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$.

The non-reduced point is the origin.
It is geometrically the $x$-axis with only the origin thickened.

There is a reduction morphism $k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)\to k[x]$ given by killing the nilpotent ideal $(y)$. This induces a morphism $\mathbf{A}^1_k\to \operatorname{Spec}k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ which must be a topological isomorphism.

The Jacobian, $J(xy,y^2)$, is given as

$$J(xy,y^2)=\begin{pmatrix}
y & x \\
0 & 2y
\end{pmatrix}:k^2\to k^2.$$

All closed points lie along the $x$-axis so that at all points other than the origin the rank of the matrix is $1$ and at the origin the rank is $0$.

Note that there are no characteristic requirements on $k$.